# Android studio - wrap in container

Tags: android-studio

Is there an equivalent feature in Android studio like Eclipse for "wrap in container"?

[image]

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079891/android-studio-wrap-in-container-in-xml-layout

Comment: `Configure > Settings > Editor > 'Use soft wraps in editor'` or 
Or right click on the divider where you can choose to show line numbers, and click 'Use soft wraps'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE(2021):** Currently, Android studio support wrap in content and you can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217255/1105277

**Original Answer(2016):**
You can use soft wrap, first solution is right click on the left of line where show line numbers and check **Use Soft Wraps**.

[image]

Another way is set it from:

> File > Settings > Editor > General > Use soft wraps in editor

Also You can set Right margin for your editor from :

> File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Right margin (columns)

Comment: This is absolutely not the answer. The Eclipse menu item in question allows you to wrap another layout around a view. Like putting a TextView inside a LinearLayout. This is not that.

Answer (score 58):

On the widget press alt+enter and choose what you want!

[image]

Comment: Mac shortcut: option + return

Answer (score 5):

For Mac ... same as above but use option+Enter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Absolutely.

**Solution 1:**

1. Select the widget.
2. Click on the Flutter Outline tab.
3. Right click on the widget.
4. Select "*Wrap with Container*".

[image]

---

**Solution 2 (recommended):**

1. Select the widget.
2. Press Option + Enter at the same time.
3. Select "*Wrap with Container*".

[image]

Comment: What is `Option` for a key in the keyboard?

Comment: 'Option' is the name of a key in a Mac keyboard. It's right between the keys 'Control' & 'Command'.