# Android Studio: 'wrap in container' in XML layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

When editing XML layout files, Eclipse has a feature called 'wrap in container' (Reformat -> Android -> ...) that lets you select one or several Views and wrap a layout of your choice around it. 
Is there something similar in Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Live Templates for that. [Here's a nice article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/code-faster-with-intellij-idea-live-templates.html) about them.

**Edit:**

New templates can be added through `File->Settings->Editor->Live Templates`.

To find the hotkey for your keymap go to `File->Settings` and write "Live template". For me it's  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>J</kbd> .

Comment: Thanks, I'll use those for the most recurring layouts until AS offers a complete solution.

Comment: CTRL + J Does nothing to android studio 1.1.0 plus the settings path you mentioned doesn't exist

Comment: @ThanosF thank you for your comment. I've updated my answer to conform to the current AS version.

Answer (score 6):

It's currently being implemented:
[Issue 69000:   Add the "Wrap In" visual refactoring - Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69000)

Tor Norbye, Android Issue Tracker Mantainer:

> We should implement the "Wrap In" visual refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this, and to complete Simas' answer:

using AS1.2, this is easy to achieve...

1. to **set up a Live Template**, simply select the View in your layout XML
   that you wanna surround. Hit `Alt+Shift+Z` (surround-with)... a little
   popup appears. Click `Configure Live Templates...`. Or use `File->Settings->Editor->Live Templates` as described above.
2. Select the `html/xml` section and hit the little `+`. Give it a name and description, then fill in template text:

   `<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="$ORIENTATION$"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
       $SELECTION$
   </LinearLayout>`
3. Click `Edit variables`, set `Expression:complete()`, `Default value:vertical`... hit OK. Then, find the `Define`' button for applicable context... and select XML.

You're all set now. To **use the template**, select the View that you wanna surround in the XML, hit `Alt+Shift+Z` (surround-with)... a little popup appears. Select the template you just defined... Done!